# Proof that thermometer will measure higher temperature than that of an enclosure if radiated heat is same in all directions

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

I am reading the English translation of J. Fourier book "The Analytical Theory of Heat".

In para 47, the author states "If the rays which escape from a heated surface had the same intensity in all directions, a thermometer placed at one of the points of a space bounded on all sides by an enclosure maintained at a constant temperature would indicate a temperature incomparably greater than that of the enclosure".

I tried searching the journal for proof of the same but couldnot find any. Can anyone provide a proof or link to the same.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph you quote states that if surfaces radiated uniformly in all directions, a thermometer in a constant temperature cavity could measure a much higher temperature than the cavity. This contradicts what is observed in practice, showing that heat is not radiated uniformly in all directions. I was likewise unable to find Fourier's proof, making it difficult to ascertain the geometry and assumptions he used. However, a couple of arguments can be made to support the point being made in the paragraph.

Firstly, it is possible to demonstrate that the thermometer can radiate heat with a different intensity to the surrounding cavity, implying these must be at different temperatures. For the sake of simplicity, assume that both the thermometer and the cavity wall absorb all incident radiation. Let a small sphere, A, with radius $r_A$ represent the thermometer. Consider heat exchange via radiation between A and a small cavity surface element, B, with area $\delta A_B$ as shown in the diagram below. The distance from A to B is $R_{AB}$.

[image: Geometry of the thermometer A and cavity surface element B.]

Let $I_A$ be the radiance of A (measured in Watts per square meter per steradian) and $I_B$ be the radiance of B. First calculate radiant heat transfer from A to B,
$$ \delta Q_{AB} = \left ( 2 \pi I_A \right ) \left ( 4 \pi r_A^2 \right ) \frac{\cos \theta \delta A_B}{4 \pi R_{AB}^2} . $$
Here the irradiance from A (equal to $2 \pi I_A$, measured in Watts per square meter) has been multiplied by the total area of A (equal to $4 \pi r_A^2$) and then by the fraction that falls on B.

Now calculate the radiant heat from B that falls on A,
$$ \delta Q_{BA} = I_B \delta A_B \frac{\pi r_A^2}{R_{AB}^2}. $$
This expression was obtained by multiplying the radiant intensity from B (measured in Watts per steradian) by the solid angle that A subtends at B.

Assuming thermal equilibrium $\delta Q_{AB} = \delta Q_{BA}$. Thus, equating and rearranging the expressions above,
$$ I_A = \frac{I_B}{2 \cos \theta} .$$
It would be possible to design a ridged cavity where $I_A$ is arbitrarily large with respect to $I_B$.

Another argument is to consider a small sphere A located on the axis of symmetry a distance of $a$ from a circular flat plate, C, that radiates heat uniformly in all directions. Integrating using cylindrical coordinates, it can be shown that:
$$ Q_{CA} = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{R_C} \frac{I_C}{r^2 + a^2} r dr $$
and hence
$$ Q_{CA} = \pi I_C \ln \left ( \frac{R_C^2 + a^2}{a^2} \right ) .$$
Here $R_C$ is the radius of the plate and $I_C$ is the radiance of C. Clearly this can become arbitrarily large as $\frac{a}{R_C} \to 0$.

The cavity geometry may be more complicated. However, if the thermometer is sufficiently close to the surface, the problem will approximate the flat plate above. Therefore, a similar conclusion will be reached when a thermometer approaches the surface of the cavity. Hence, temperature measured by a thermometer increases without limit approaching the surfaces of a cavity which radiates heat uniformly in all directions.